# read/get http post data by shopify on url

Tags: c#, asp.net, e-commerce, shopify

I have created a webhook
**Order payment** and given URL **http://example.com/shopifydata.htm**

Now I want to get all the data posted by shopify on order payment in C#

I have following code

```
 HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/shopifydata.htm");
                myRequest.Method = "Get";

                //if needs credential you can use myRequest.Credentials
                using (HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    StreamReader mysr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("GB2312"));
                    //get the string content you can see what it is
                    string responseResult = mysr.ReadToEnd();

                }
```

But I am not able to get anything

Where as when I use **http://requestb.in/** I am able to get data. But can't get success on my site page

Please advise
Thanks

Comment: `But I am not able to get anything`...this statement is extremely vague, if you want some help PLEASE explain why you think you can't get anything...you MUST be getting something...at least, an error. Do you realize that `example.com` is just a random domain????

Comment: there is no post data

Comment: mate, you are confusing me. Are you posting data? You seem to be issuing a `GET` request here...`myRequest.Method = "Get";`...do you have any idea of what you are doing?

Comment: @Leo , when you shop on shopify, shopify posts some data after completing the transactions on given page URL, so i have given an url that i mentioned in question, now i have to fetch all those data, like user pay some order, then i have to get all transaction details from the page where shopify posts data after payement